# dynamically adding nginx container ip into phpfpm /etc/hosts file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Looking to automatically add the nginx container ip address inside my phpfpm container /etc/hosts file.

Inside my yml file, I have a service called phpfpm, and I know you can use extra_hosts attribute to assign values into the /etc/hosts file, however I don't know how to dynamically call place the nginx container IP.

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ../public/:/var/www/html/public/
    container_name: nginx
    networks: 
      - backend

  phpfpm:
    build: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../public/:/var/www/html/public/
    container_name: phpfpm
    extra_hosts:
      - "test.local:nginx" <insert nginx ip to test.local>
    networks: 
      - backend
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers within a compose file will run on same network and you can just their names. `phpfpm` and `nginx` in your case. Also if you need more names for the same service you need to use aliases

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ../public/:/var/www/html/public/
    container_name: nginx
    networks: 
      backend:
        aliases:
          - test.local

  phpfpm:
    build: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../public/:/var/www/html/public/
    container_name: phpfpm
    networks: 
      - backend
```

Comment: Yeah, since there are multiple websites sitting on the nginx pointing into the phpfpm container, one of the scripts wants to do a curl to a particular website. So I need to bind the domains to an ip so it can call the correct files.

Comment: So in your code if it curls `test.local` with no `extra_hosts` defined and a alias defined, it would work

Comment: Thanks this works great, I didn't see they had this feature!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Nginx Ip address? You can call nginx from phpfpm container by hostname `nginx`

Comment: I have a script within my php container that allows me to manage multiple wordpress websites, and it seems like that scripts uses curl to fetch the website and signs in. Since the phpfpm and nginx are sitting on different containers, it seems like manually binding the domain into the host file fixes the issue.