# Communication between multiple hosts of nginx in docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  LEMP:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "3333:3333"
    volumes:
      - /var/www:/var/www
      - ./nginx-conf/server1.local.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/server1.local.conf
      - ./nginx-conf/server2.local.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/server2.local.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - LEMP
    extra_hosts:
      - "server1.local:127.0.0.1"
      - "server2.local:127.0.0.1"
  php:
    build: ./php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/www:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - LEMP
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_password
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - LEMP
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - LEMP

volumes:
  db:
```

PHP Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www
```

If I try to reach server1.local or server2.local from my browser / postman it works fine, but if I try to reach server2.local (REST api) from server1.local, it can't reach it.

I read [this discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/trying-to-make-to-different-hosts-of-the-same-nginx-container-to-communicate/44256) but of course I can't use my PC IP since the configuration will be shared to other colleagues.
I know nginx-proxy, but this last one requires to setup other services where projects are, but in my case I have only git projects stored in /var/www/, so how should I setup them starting from a folder in /var/www? For example, server2.local has both php and an internal reverse proxy for a local host (localhost:3333). Should I start from php image, install node.js/pm2, run them and so on? It seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with server1 and server2? If you have 3 nodes (nginx, server1, server2) that should work in conjunction why don't you place all three of them together in same docker-compose, in same network and they will see each other by service name?

Comment: They are in the same network, same docker-compose and same "service" (nginx), as you can see in the example above. They are just hosts of nginx. server1.local.conf reads "server1.local" and "server2.local.conf reads "server2.local". If I can't explain myself better, check out this discussion, he has the same problem: https://forums.docker.com/t/trying-to-make-to-different-hosts-of-the-same-nginx-container-to-communicate/44256

Comment: They are not in same docker-compose file judging from what you posted, you have separate files handling php, right? I've now read the discussion you listed and my question is directly related to this part: "you MIGHT be able to make this easier with docker-compose and a ‘named’ network for the containers…" from cited discussion. Seems to me you are in same position as if you had database+api containers that need to communicate => named services, same net, same docker-compose => they see each other by service name...

Comment: It extracted that part only from my docker-compose, pardon. I updated it with the full docker-compose.

Comment: Then you should be able to see them based on service name. Say, instead of server1.local you should be able to use just 'php' (supposing php is server1.local).

Comment: Actually server1 and server2 are both on the same service (nginx/php), if I use "php" or "nginx" it won't be able to distinguish them

Comment: then this line of your question is confusing: `but if I try to reach server2.local (REST api) from server1.local, it can't reach it.`. You have 4 services (containers): nginx,php,mysql,redis. You have server1.local and server2.local. My question is: which of those containers server1.local and server2.local should resolve to, and from which containers are you going to target them (all 4, just some?).

Comment: server1 and server2 are in "nginx", so they should resolve that container and they does, from "outside" (browser, postman), but internally

Comment: You need to use aliases as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750752/dynamically-adding-nginx-container-ip-into-phpfpm-etc-hosts-file/45752538#45752538